# MS Access VBA: Syntax Error in Update Statement

Tags: ms-access, syntax, vba

I'm relatively new at compiling VBA code in MS Access.  I'm trying to compile a script which performs incremental row updates in order to add a row number to an underlying table.

My current VBA script is as follows:

```
Function HOP_Macro()
On Error GoTo HOP_Macro_Err

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim Tbl As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    Dim Row_Counter As Integer
    Dim Total_Row As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'Initialising Row Counter variable
    Row_Counter = 1

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    ' Query to extract initial loan population
    'DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry - HOP loan data by month", acViewNormal, acEdit

    ' Query to determine the population size
    'DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry - Row Counter", acViewNormal, acEdit

    ' Sets Total_Row variable to the population count
    Total_Row = DLookup("[Row Count]", "[Tbl - Record Counter]")
    'MsgBox ("Total Row: " & Total_Row)
    'MsgBox ("Row Counter: " & Row_Counter)

    sql = "SELECT [Tbl - HOP Loan Data].[Row ID] FROM [Tbl - HOP Loan Data];"
    Set Tbl = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)
    'MsgBox ("SQL 1: " & sql)

    With Tbl
        Do Until Tbl.EOF
            If Row_Counter <= Total_Row Then
                'MsgBox ("Hello")
                sql = "UPDATE [Tbl - HOP Loan Data.Row ID] = " & Row_Counter & _
                " Where [Tbl - HOP Loan Data.Row ID] < " & Row_Counter & " ;"
                'MsgBox ("SQL 2: " & sql)
                db.Execute (sql)
                Row_Counter = Row_Counter + 1
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    MsgBox ("Row Counter: " & Row_Counter)

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Beep
    MsgBox "Data extract complete", vbInformation, "Completed"

End Function
```

When running the above script, I get a "Syntax error in UPDATE statement" message.  I am unable to find the error.  Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

```
Function Set_Row_ID()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim Tbl As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    Dim Row_Counter As Integer
    Dim Total_Row As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'Initialising Row Counter variable
    Row_Counter = 1

    sql = "SELECT [Tbl - HOP Loan Data].[Row ID] FROM [Tbl - HOP Loan Data];"
    Set Tbl = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)

    With Tbl
        Do Until Tbl.EOF
            If Row_Counter <= Total_Row Then
                sql = "UPDATE [Tbl - HOP Loan Data " & _
                    "SET [Row ID] = " & Row_Counter & _
                    "Where [Row ID] < " & Row_Counter & " ;"
                db.Execute (sql)
                Row_Counter = Row_Counter + 1
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SET` in your Update Query, you probably just missed it with all the extrenuous VBA stuff you needed to add into the query.

My suggestion (in general) is the write the query normally, through Access, and then modify that query for use in VBA.

For instance, write this query first like so (in Access SQL Editor, for testing purposes):

```
UPDATE [Tbl - HOP Loan Data]
SET [Tbl - HOP Loan Data].[Row ID] = 1
WHERE [Tbl - HOP Loan Data].[Row ID] < 1
```

Anyway, try this:

```
sql = "UPDATE [Tbl - HOP Loan Data] " & _
    "SET [Tbl - HOP Loan Data].[Row ID] = " & Row_Counter & _
    "WHERE [Tbl - HOP Loan Data].[Row ID] < " & Row_Counter & " ;"
```

*NOTE*: The `WHERE` statement is *most likely* unnecessary, depending on your table structure.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Jiggles32, however I'm still stuck.

Comment: To clarify the purpose of the code:  The "Row ID" field within the "Tbl - HOP Loan Data" table is intended to represent the row number (i.e. a sequential count) for subsequent referencing.

The SQL which creates the initial table will set a default value of "0" for all lines.  The VBA coding was then coding to update the individual values incrementally - hence the section of VBA with the "where condition" (i.e. I only want to update the rows where the Row ID field is less than the Row-Counter variable).

Comment: Current code is as follows:
With Tbl
        Do Until Tbl.EOF
            If Row_Counter <= Total_Row Then
               sql = "UPDATE [Tbl - HOP Loan Data " & _
                    "SET [Tbl - HOP Loan Data].[Row ID] = " & Row_Counter
                db.Execute (sql)
                Row_Counter = Row_Counter + 1
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

Comment: Is there perhaps an easier way to get the required end result?  I am open to suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Solution found.  Answer has been posted.